# Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Ion_auth_model Using "Ion Auth"

Tags: codeigniter-3

After Renaming "model" folder then I revert back folder name to "model" and facing this issue:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: RuntimeException

Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Ion_auth_model

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\paper_auth\system\core\Loader.php

Line Number: 348

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\paper_auth\application\libraries\Ion_auth.php
Line: 74
Function: model

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\paper_auth\application\controllers\Book_Class.php
Line: 7
Function: __construct

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\paper_auth\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

my code was working properly before renaming I did it by mistake using "PHPStorm" can any one please help me?

Comment: I am using Windows and my model names are like "Model_Name_model" and I call them like "$this->model->load('model_name_model');"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a typo in your question, but if not the folder name is "**models**" not "**model**".

Comment: No it is not a typo in my question. and folder name is "model" not "models" I have checked every aspect before posting my question here.

Comment: You are right bro It solved my problem name of folder was "models" and then when I revert back it I renamed it like "model" Thanks!!